# Python: button command isn't running?

Tags: python, button, methods, tkinter

For an A-level computing project, I am making a car data monitoring system. I have a button that opens the `filedialog.askopenfilename` method. When I pass this through a method like below, it doesn't work. However when I pass it straight into the button, it works fine. Any ideas as to why?

Doesn't work:

```
def get_data_file():
    filedialog.askopenfilename
    return
OpenfileButton=Button(master,text="Select File",width=20,command=get_data_file).grid(row=3, column=2)
```

works:

```
OpenfileButton=Button(master,text="Select File",width=20,command=filedialog.askopenfilename).grid(row=3, column=2)
```

Comment: You need to call the function in the first example. Just add () to the end of `askopenfilename`. Also you don't need the return.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Post as answer and i'll +1 @PaulRooney

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually call the function

```
def get_data_file():
    filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

When you pass the function to the button you should not call it but simply pass it to be called when the button is clicked, but as you have now wrapped it in another function it must be called by you.

The return is redundant and can be left out if you wish. All python functions return `None` by default.